# In Zebra RW420 , line print mode not working in android

Tags: android, zebra-printers, barcode-printing

I am using zebra rw420 printer for printing a bill from my android mobile just like the image.[image]

When I trying to print a label it is working fine.
but when I try to print in line-print mode it is giving a blank print.
Code I am using is

```
String cpclConfigLabel = "! U1 setvar {0} {1}, \"device.languages\", \"line_print\"\r\n"
            + "!U1 SETLP 5 2 46\r\n"
            + "AURORA'S FABRIC SHOP\r\n"
            + "!U1 SETLP 5 2 24\r\n" + "123 CASTLE DRIVE";

    try {
        configLabel = cpclConfigLabel.getBytes("US-ASCII");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
printerConnection.write(configLabel);
```

I am using Developer Demo from Zebra sdk,

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

The SDK was not designed for use with the printers in line mode. It will upon detecting that the printer is in line mode put it in ZPL mode.

The reason for this is that the SDK is set up to allow for status checking, template printing, and some other functions that will not work when the printer is in line mode.

Changing the printer back to line mode like you are trying to do will work for the printing portion, but if you try to use the status commands or some of the other SDK features you will start to get exceptions.

To print receipts and invoices which are variable length in ZPL you can do the following:

1. Set the printer media mode to continuous.
2. Create a template for the receipt header, line, and footer.

2a. Each of those templates will be a fixed height so set the "^LL" command for each template.

2b. Set the orientation of the template to inverted "^POI"

2b. Each of those templates have variables that can be filled in

3. Split your runtime data and recall the formats filling in the data.

You will essentially use templates instead of printing each line

Header

Line

Line

...

Line

Footer

Comment: is there any problem if we comment status checking and template printing portion?? if no how can we do that?? because  i only need printing text from the printer. please reply.when i printed the printercontrollerlanguage it is giving cpcl.

Comment: if we can't use this sdk in line print mode , then how we can print receipts with variable length from android using zebra printers?please help.

Comment: Banno can you please show me with an example code??

Answer (score 1):

Noticed a few syntax errors:
First line: remove '{0} {1}, ' and comma as well. It should read "! U1 setvar \"device.languages\" \"line_print\"\r\n".
Second and fourth line: insert a space between '!' and 'U1'.

Comment: Thankz for ur help..I tried the above edits... but now also the same situation.its not working.

Comment: do you have any other solution?